# How to kill a process and keep it killed so it cannot come back?

Tags: 14.04, steam

So hello AU :D

I’ve been playing some TF2 and on a lot of servers there are ads (video ads) and they loop it and it goes on forever.

I’ve been told that you can mute/destroy the ads if you kill the process it stops the ad. The process is steamwebhelper and that’s the ad, its in the background, I try to kill the process, it does work for a little bit then it will come back. And then I have to kill it again and so on...

Is there anyway too keep a process killed so it cannot come back again?

I’m aware that the steam web helper also shows deals on games and such but I really don’t need any of that, I just want to play without the ads and the pop ups.

If any other information is needed please ask :D

I am running Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use my method. Each time when i want end all game and steam, I use this command.

```
pkill -9 -f steam
```